# Error while de-serializing json to MyClass.java: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization, jackson-databind

**MyClass.java:**

```
class MyClass<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable{

    @JsonProperty(value = "allowedValues", required = false)
    private List<T> allowedValues;
}
```

I'm getting this exception while deserializing this above object persisted in the DB.
How do i resolve this?

Error while de-serializing json to MyClass.java: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of java.io.Serializable (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information at [Source: (String)"{"allowedValues":["a","b","c"]} (through reference chain: com.babu.model.MyClass->["allowedValues"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])

Comment: probably one of those objects in the list does not have a default constructor (with no arguments)

Comment: You can use json ignore for sometimes helping to bypass unused vars.

Comment: @LazarPetrovic Yes , you are correct. but If you look at the example , while desterilizing it unable to construct the  allowedValues because of the abstract type (T extends Serializable). In this case , we can't define the default constructors

Comment: Can you provide more details about how this is failing for you?  This code appears to work:

MyClass<?> myClass = objectMapper.readValue("{\"allowedValues\": [\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"]}", MyClass.class);

Comment: @BabuPasungily it looks like it doesn't even know which class to instantiate. How did you serialize the data?